# eloquent laravel have raw join with where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a piece of my code I need to change from this

```
->rightJoin('calendar', function($join) use ($machineName)
{
    $join->on('print_jobs.job_date', '=', 'calendar.datefield')
         ->where('machines.machine', '=', $machineName);
})
```

To

```
->rightJoin('calendar', function($join) use ($machineName)
{
    $join->on('DATE(print_jobs.job_date)', '=', 'calendar.datefield')
         ->where('machines.machine', '=', $machineName);
})
```

Notice I am changing the print_jobs.job_date from datetime to date.  This worked fine until i changed the field from date to a datetime.

Eloquent does not like me adding DATE here.  I dont know how to just put the raw join field here.

Comment: Try DB::raw('DATE(print_jobs.job_date)') instead of 'DATE(print_jobs.job_date)' and don't forget: use DB;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Eloquent, this is the fluent query builder, to be clear. Next, the issue is that it doesn't know how to handle `DATE()` because it only expects a string, not a method. To work around this, use the`raw()` method off of the DB facade. I've included the full namespace below, but you can just `use` it at the top of the file and reference `DB::raw()` for brevity.

```
$join->on(Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::raw('DATE(print_jobs.job_date)'), '=', 'calendar.datefield')
```

Comment: Thanks.  I new DB::raw but kept trying to use it outside the on call, not inside.  This solved it.